# why const before template parameter does not work

Tags: c++, templates

I'm so confused why the following code doesn't work?

The compiler says:
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
6 |     const T a = 1;

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    const T a = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int& k = i;
    f(k);
}
```

Comment: `const typename std::remove_reference<decltype(t)>::type& a = 1;`

Answer (score 3):

with `f(k);` we call `template<typename T> void f(T&& t)` with `T = int&`.

`const T` is not `const int&` (nor `int const&`) but `int&` (as `const` applied to reference is useless).

and

`int& a = 1;` is invalid.

Comment: Why (as const applied to reference is useless) ? Is that T& is not a type so we cannot add const?

Comment: @Baker-xie A "reference to const int" makes sense, but a "const reference to int" does not since the reference itself can never be modified, only the thing it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other response, you can easily see that if you're using east const style:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    T const a = 1;
}
```

Now, the compiler would instantiate into something that looks like this:

```
template<>
void f(int& t) {
    int& const a = 1;
}
```

The `const` keywords always applies to the thing on its left, unless there is none.

It applies on the whole reference, but references can't be changed in C++ so it doesn't change anything!

So this is pretty much equivalent to:

```
template<>
void f(int& t) {
    int& a = 1;
}
```

Which as the other answers says, invalid.